# How to print out all the keys and subkeys of an object

Tags: javascript

JSFiddle version with spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/eopth925/1/

```js
var obj = {
 test: {
   test2: "test",
    test3: {
     base: {
       base: {
         check: function() {
           return this;
          },
          va: function() {
           return "value";
          },
          do: "this is dummy"
        }
      }
    },
    test4: {
     test5: function() {
       var k = 2;
        k++;
        
        return k;
      },
      test6: {
       test7: {
         test8: "test8",
          test9: {
           test10: "test10",
            test11: function() {
             return window.jQuery;
            },
            test12: "test12",
            test13: function() {
             return window.ga;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  
};

var output = "";
var addbreak = "\n";

var RunFunc = {
  propertypri: function(a) {
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function(e) {
      if (typeof a[e] === 'object') {
        output += `Main Key=${e}`;
        RunFunc.propertyobj(e, a[e]);
      }
      else {
        output += `Main Key=${e} value=${a[e]}` + addbreak;
      }
    });
    console.log(output);
  },
  propertyobj: function(key, keyObj) {
    Object.keys(keyObj).forEach(function(e) {
      if (typeof keyObj[e] === 'object') {
        output += ` Subkey=${e}`;
        RunFunc.propertyobj(e, keyObj[e]);
      }
      else {
        output += ` Subkey=${e} value=${keyObj[e]}` + addbreak;
      }
    });
  }
};

RunFunc.propertypri(obj);
```

The way it's outputting is not view friendly. I would like to add proper indentation in the output. I am sure there is a more efficient way of doing what I am trying to accomplish.

How can I update my script so it displays like this:

```
Main Key=test
  Subkey=test2 value=test
  Subkey=test3
    Subkey=base
      Subkey=base
        Subkey=check value=function() {
            return this;
          }
        Subkey=va value=function() {
            return "value";
          }
        Subkey=do value=this is dummy
  Subkey=test4
    Subkey=test5 value=function() {
        var k = 2;
        k++;

        return k;
      }
    Subkey=test6
      Subkey=test7
        Subkey=test8 value=test8
        Subkey=test9
          Subkey=test10 value=test10
          Subkey=test11 value=function() {
                return window.jQuery;
            }
            ...
```

Comment: I played around with your example for a little bit and I managed to rename few keys using recursion, but I still havent got the full answer. I believe with recursion you will be able to do it. Anyway, this is a good brain teaser, if I manage to solve, I will post!

Comment: Yeah... trying to auto format for a document but I will work on it as well... Thanks. Please post once you figured it out. The only thing I am not sure is... once we finished with `test3` how do know so we can start with ` ` for `test4`.

Comment: I figured it out and i will post the answer once I have tested it working.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use `JSON.stringify`?

console.log(JSON.stringify(foo, (key, val) => (typeof val === 'function' ? '' + val : val), 2))

Comment: Ehh, not sure why I was downvoted. The output format the asker is requesting is unbelievably noisy.

Comment: I am not sure why but that's the request and thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score -2):

const yourObject = { /* object properties here */ }

```js
function printKeys(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj)
    for (const key of keys) {
      printKeys(key)
    }
  } else {
    console.log(obj)
  }
}
```

Comment: OP asked *"How can I update my script so it displays like this:"*, but the output of your code would look nothing like what OP has requested (indentation, `Main key` and `subkey` labels, etc).